# web app crashes on startup in iPad

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, ipad

I have a web app, i use java script, html, css.
When i open the app in safari it works fine, but when i save it to the home screen and open there some times it crashes.

This happens in iPad Air and iPad mini both with latest ios.

Does any one have this problem or any idea what may cause this?

I have the following meta tags, don't know if has any influence:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="title">
```